# SQL Sorted Count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have the following table sorted by date:

| date | id |
| --- | --- |
| 9/1/20 | 1 |
| 9/1/20 | 2 |
| 9/3/20 | 1 |
| 9/4/20 | 3 |
| 9/4/20 | 2 |
| 9/6/20 | 1 |

I'd like to add a count column for each id so that the first count for each id is the earliest date and latest date would receive the highest count for each id:

| date | id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/1/20 | 1 | 1 |
| 9/1/20 | 2 | 1 |
| 9/3/20 | 1 | 2 |
| 9/4/20 | 3 | 1 |
| 9/4/20 | 2 | 2 |
| 9/6/20 | 1 | 3 |

How can I structure my Postgresql query to assemble this count column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
from t
order by date, id;
```